# Websocket binary data messages (ArrayBuffer)

Tags: javascript, websocket, typed-arrays

As I understand `ArrayBuffer` length is set only by constructor and cannot be changed dynamically. So I am curious, is it possible using websockets binary data messages send arraybuffer certain part, not whole buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.slice` to slice an `ArrayBuffer`: http://jsfiddle.net/rtaB4/21/.

```
var inputBuffer = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).buffer;
var outputBuffer = inputBuffer.slice(1, 3);

console.log(outputBuffer.byteLength);       // 2
console.log(new Uint8Array(outputBuffer));  // [1, 2]
```

Comment: Websocket can only send ArrayBuffer not Uint8Array or others

Comment: @Demion: I know, the input and output is an `ArrayBuffer` here (`origBuffer` and `buffer`).

Comment: @konga raju: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: But slice produce new Array. This is not GC-Friendly. Does anyone knows better way?

Answer (score 0):

Read these articles the specification was changed.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String